# which plugin is this?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

[image: which plugin is this]

i want to know which plugin is this or similar types of plugin https://www.variyoshop.com/product/free-fire-diamond-direct-from-player-id-top-up/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website is using Woocommerce which is an open-source e-commerce plugin for WordPress.
I found it using [Builtwith](https://builtwith.com/?https%3A%2F%2Fwww.variyoshop.com%2Fproduct%2Ffree-fire-diamond-direct-from-player-id-top-up%2F).

Cannot say exactly which Product Addon plugin it could be using though. However, If you want a free Wordpress Plugin then you can find it here :

- [Product Addons for Woocommerce By Acowebs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-product-addons/)
- [PPOM for WooCommerce By Najeeb Ahmad](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-addon/)

I have purely recommended these as a suggestion and do not endorse any of the above plugins. Please vote if I was helpful. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

It is using the Woocommerce Custom Product Addons. It can be found here:
https://acowebs.com/woo-custom-product-addons/

Comment: it is paid ones can i get free one

Comment: They do have the free version which can be found in wordpress.org:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-product-addons/